# Redirection using Content editor Webpart 

Tags: web-part

Whenever i try to open a site , i want page to redirect to some other page .
So , i have added a javascript to redirect using the content editor on my page .
Now i want to edit the code added to Content editor . But i am unable to find the page in edit mode because the script run and its being redirected .
How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the webpart maintainance page by adding ?contents=1 to the page and delete the webpart and add it again to page

Comment: this will work the best and easiest . .
all other approaches are also working g8 . .
thx to all :)

Answer (score 2):

Best practice would be to create the javascript file and upload it to a -Script Library-. 
Then just reference that file in the Content Editor WebPart, that way you could always just edit the source file.

By default, there is also a redirect page layout type that gets created when publishing is enabled. You may want to take a look at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Thomson's answer, but give a try in SharePoint Designer too

Answer (score 0):

Either Sharepoint designer or if you're using publishing pages, you can just go to the Pages library and edit the content there.

You can also try to disable javascript before going to the page - Not sure how much of the core editing will work though.